# More efficient MYSQL Wordpress join/view Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress

My current query that lists some information from the WordPress User/usermeta database doesn't complete, slows and pretty much halts its operation till i stop the process.

is there a more efficient way of doing this query? i was thinking that selecting all the data and placing it in another table to allow for easier reporting would be better. However, I'm not that good at MYSQL and so wasn't sure what the best approach is.

```
SELECT 
u1.ID, 
u1.user_login, 
u1.user_email, 
m1.meta_value AS Gender, 
m2.meta_value AS Username,
m3.meta_value AS Country, 
m4.meta_value AS PassedSup,
m5.meta_value AS StartbeingSup,
m6.meta_value AS StoppedbeingSup,
m7.meta_value AS PassedTutor,
m8.meta_value AS CurrentlyaTutor,
m9.meta_value AS StartBeingTutor,
m10.meta_value AS StopBeingTutor,
m11.meta_value AS NoOfChildren,
m12.meta_value AS CurrentSupervisor,
m13.meta_value AS SecondSupervisor,
m14.meta_value AS Volunteer,
m15.meta_value AS VolunteerStart,
m16.meta_value AS VolunteerEnd,
m17.meta_value AS SupervisorName,
m18.meta_value AS NameOfTutor,
m19.meta_value AS DBSNo,
m20.meta_value AS DBSStart,
m21.meta_value AS Ref2
FROM wp_users u1
JOIN wp_usermeta m1 ON ( m1.user_id = u1.ID AND m1.meta_key = 'gender')
JOIN wp_usermeta m2 ON ( m2.user_id = u1.ID AND m2.meta_key = 'username_or_email')
JOIN wp_usermeta m3 ON ( m3.user_id = u1.ID AND m3.meta_key = 'country')
JOIN wp_usermeta m4 ON ( m4.user_id = u1.ID AND m4.meta_key = 'date_supervizor')
JOIN wp_usermeta m5 ON ( m5.user_id = u1.ID AND m5.meta_key = 'sup_start_date')
JOIN wp_usermeta m6 ON ( m6.user_id = u1.ID AND m6.meta_key = 'sup_end_date')
JOIN wp_usermeta m7 ON ( m7.user_id = u1.ID AND m7.meta_key = 'date_tutor')
JOIN wp_usermeta m8 ON ( m8.user_id = u1.ID AND m8.meta_key = 'is_tutor')
JOIN wp_usermeta m9 ON ( m9.user_id = u1.ID AND m9.meta_key = 'tutor_start')
JOIN wp_usermeta m10 ON ( m10.user_id = u1.ID AND m10.meta_key = 'tutor_end')
JOIN wp_usermeta m11 ON ( m11.user_id = u1.ID AND m11.meta_key = 'no_child')
JOIN wp_usermeta m12 ON ( m12.user_id = u1.ID AND m12.meta_key = 'Current_Supervizor')
JOIN wp_usermeta m13 ON ( m13.user_id = u1.ID AND m13.meta_key = 'supervizor_2')
JOIN wp_usermeta m14 ON ( m14.user_id = u1.ID AND m14.meta_key = 'volunteer')
JOIN wp_usermeta m15 ON ( m15.user_id = u1.ID AND m15.meta_key = 'volunteer_start')
JOIN wp_usermeta m16 ON ( m16.user_id = u1.ID AND m16.meta_key = 'volunteer_end')
JOIN wp_usermeta m17 ON ( m17.user_id = u1.ID AND m17.meta_key = 'Name_of_tutor')
JOIN wp_usermeta m18 ON ( m18.user_id = u1.ID AND m18.meta_key = 'DBS_NO')
JOIN wp_usermeta m19 ON ( m19.user_id = u1.ID AND m19.meta_key = 'DBS_start_date')
JOIN wp_usermeta m20 ON ( m20.user_id = u1.ID AND m20.meta_key = 'date_membership_passed')
JOIN wp_usermeta m21 ON ( m21.user_id = u1.ID AND m21.meta_key = 'ref_2')
```

Comment: This query assumes that all the data exists. Is that really true? That said, it's pretty efficient. There is an alternative method. It's more elegant but it's no more efficient

Comment: @Strawberry the metakey table data will always be there (so the column names) however, there inst always the value for that user. i wonder what i could do then if wordpress / phpmyadmind keeps dying.

Comment: Your query is good enough and also can check with wp database description: 

https://codex.wordpress.org/Database_Description#Table:_wp_usermeta

Comment: If all the entities and attributes exist for each user (albeit with some blank values) then this query is fine. Otherwise, you'd need to rewrite it with LEFT JOINSs. If entity and attribute are indexed (and surely they must be as they're certainly UNIQUE and/or PRIMARY) then I don't think there's that much more you can do performance-wise :-(